# How to trace boundary of multiple objects manually in binary image using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, binary-image

**I want to trace the boundary of an object manually using python in binary images without using OpenCV. I am done with one object but I want to trace multiple objects in an image without using OpenCV findContours.**

**original image :**

[image]

**output image :**

[image]

I tried using the Moore neighborhood algorithm on binary images. It is tracing the boundary for one object only. I want to trace all the objects.

My code showing the output for one object only and I want to trace for all.